# Use createTrackbar to display type

Tags: opencv

I'm using createTrackbar in openCV to choose different actions on image: rotate, resize, or thresholding, etc. Basicactions is the callback function.

```
createTrackbar(trackbar_type, window_name, 
                &type_action, type_max, basicactions);

void basicactions( int, void* )
{
    switch(type_action)
    {
    case 0: // Original image
        {
            imshow(window_name,im);
            break;
        }
    case 1: // Change contrast
        {
            double contrast = (double) (2*value-255);
            Mat out=imcontrast(im,contrast);
            imshow( window_name, out );
            break;
        }
    case 2: //Resizing
        {
```

The problem is I want to display the current action to the user. However, the trackbar can only display number. And the name of trackbar can not be displayed in full size on Windows (it's shortened). Anyway to display string in trackbar instead of number?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

no, not possible.

maybe createButton() for each of your actions instead